# How to change the name of identifiers in cloud connect?

Tags: cloud-connect

Is there any way to change the name of **identifiers** in **cloud connect** in the model.
Case is that when I am trying to change the name of identifiers of any attribute or fact the then cloud connect first deleted that specific attribute/fact and generating a new attribute/fact.
And because of this metrics which use the fact(for which I am changing the identifiers) is deleted.